# Define global variable in Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Jenkins Shared Library with many functions into /vars. Among them, there is a `devopsProperties.groovy` with many properties :

```
class devopsProperties {

    //HOSTS & SLAVES
    final String delivery_host = "****"
    final String yamale_slave = "****"

    //GIT
    final Map<String,String> git_orga_by_project = [
        "project1" : "orga1",
        "project2" : "orga2",
        "project3" : "orga3"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Other functions in my Shared Library use these parameters. For example, `gitGetOrga.groovy` :

```
def call(String project_name) {
    devopsProperties.git_orga_by_project.each{
        if (project_name.startsWith(it.key)){
            orga_found = it.value
        }
    }
    return orga_found
}
```

But now, as we have many environments, we need to load at the beginning of the pipeline the devopsProperties. I create properties files in the resources :

```
+-resources
 +-properties
  +-properties-dev.yaml
  +-properties-val.yaml
  +-properties-prod.yaml
```

and create a function to load it :

```
def call(String environment="PROD") {
    // load the specific environment properties file
    switch(environment.toUpperCase()) { 
        case "DEV": 
            def propsText = libraryResource 'properties/properties-dev.yaml'
            devopsProperties = readYaml text:propsText
            print "INFO : DEV properties loaded" 
            break
        case "VAL":
            def propsText = libraryResource 'properties/properties-val.yaml'
            devopsProperties = readYaml text:propsText
            print "INFO : VAl properties loaded" 
            break
        case "PROD": 
            def propsText = libraryResource 'properties/properties-prod.yaml'
            devopsProperties = readYaml text:propsText
            print "INFO : PROD properties loaded" 
            break
        default:
            print "ERROR : environment unkown, choose between DEV, VAL or PROD"
            break
    }
    return devopsProperties
}
```

but when I try to use it in a pipeline :

```
@Library('Jenkins-SharedLibraries')_

devopsProperties = initProperties("DEV")

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("SLAVE JENKINS") {
            agent {
                node {
                    label ***
                }
            }
            stages{
                stage('Test') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            print devopsProperties.delivery_host // THIS IS OK
                            print devopsProperties.git_orga_by_project["project1"] // THIS IS OK
                            print gitGetOrga("project1") //THIS IS NOT OK
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last print generates an error : `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: devopsProperties for class: gitGetOrga`

How I can use a global variable into all my Jenkins Shared Library functions ? If possible, I prefer to not pass it in parameter of all functions.

Comment: What is the second global variable method named?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you imply, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
First, you need to place `gitGetOrga.groovy` in to 'src' directory which is on the same level as `var` and where you have java package for your code. You'll get the structure like this:

[image]

After that, you need to import your class in `gitGetOrga.groovy`

```
import com.you-company.project-name.devopsProperties

def call(String project_name) {
    devopsProperties.git_orga_by_project.each{
        if (project_name.startsWith(it.key)){
            orga_found = it.value
        }
    }
    return orga_found
}
```

You can find more information in the Jenkins docs: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#writing-libraries

Comment: Have you tested this? I am quite sure `import` does work with slashes...

Comment: Yes, but this is not the best way to achieve your goal. I've updated my previous answers accordingly.